# How to show a div for 10 seconds and hide it after?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a div that will be hidden after 10 seconds of the page loading, is it possible to be done in PHP or JavaScript.

Code Example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="LOADING" id="LOADING" name="LOADING"></div>
<div class="HOME_MENU" id="HOME_MENU" name="HOME_MENU"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with an onload on the body - which self-triggers a setTimeout and starts when the page is loaded.

```js
function hideLoadingDiv() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('LOADING').classList.add('hidden');
  },10000)
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="hideLoadingDiv()">
<div class="LOADING" id="LOADING" name="LOADING">Loading</div>
<div class="HOME_MENU" id="HOME_MENU" name="HOME_MENU">Menu</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="LOADING" id="LOADING" name="LOADING">LOADING</div>
<div class="HOME_MENU" id="HOME_MENU" name="HOME_MENU">HOME_MENU</div>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('LOADING').style.display = 'none';
    }, 10000); // 10000ms = 10s
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it's working

Answer (score 0):

This is done with Javascript. You can add a script that sets a time out to hide the div after a number of seconds.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="LOADING" id="LOADING" name="LOADING"></div>
<div class="HOME_MENU" id="HOME_MENU" name="HOME_MENU"></div>


<script>
// Get the element by id using javascript
var divElement = document.getElementById('LOADING');

  // after 10 seconds (10 000 milliseconds), execute the function to hide it
  setTimeOut(function () {
     // hide the divElement. There are a couple of ways. In this case, let's
     // just give it a display of none
     divElement.style.display = 'none'
  }, 10000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your code working? I see there is a typo in setTimeOut. It should be setTimeout.